# Using Kinesis and AWS lambda how does one track retries and when a batch is out of retries?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I can see messages like

```
START RequestId: 3fcc8e32-8736-4c9c-ba8e-6c57b97837ff
```

and

```
END RequestId: 3fcc8e32-8736-4c9c-ba8e-6c57b97837ff
```

But I know that I've had errors in my lambda that lead to the the lambda retrying. I was wondering if there's any default cloudwatch metrics or what cloudwatch log keywords we can look for in the case of both a retry and in the case of being out of retries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Lambda would use the same request id for a retry of an asynchronous invocation. You may be able to use Cloudwatch insights to check for duplicate request ids and if there were three of them. Three being the maximum number of invocations for an asynchronous request.

**update**

This [CloudWatch insights query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html) will show the Lambda invocations which had more that one of the same request id. Thus the asynchronous invocations which failed at least once.

```
stats count(*) as requestIdCount by @requestId 
| filter @message like /START RequestId/
| filter requestIdCount > 1
```

**Sample output**

```
# @requestId                           requestIdCount
1 c0d5a65a-7db3-413e-8d1f-4b9da0f21a71 3
```

---

In the case of [Kinesis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html) Lambda is invoked synchronously so there's not a clear identifier of which request the sdk retried. Though I would think the solution there would be to add a udid to the data being written to Kinesis and then search the Lambda function's logs for that similar to the above.